# Flight delayed and immigration in BKK

Tags: air-travel, transit, luggage

The passenger is travelling CMB - BKK with Sri Lankan Airlines (UL) and BKK - KMG with Lucky Air (8L). If the first flight with UL is delayed by 20 minutes, the passenger has only 1 hour and 10 minutes to get on the next flight with his bags. What will be the best option to get his boarding pass and bags checked-in on the BKK - KMG flight with 8L? UL airline does not provide him with a through check-in option. And does he need to go through Immigration?

I am afraid that the passenger will miss the flight or his bags will not be transferred.

Comment: Please don't just use airport codes. They're more susceptible to errors (e.g., people assuming that DUB is Dubai when it's actually Dublin), typos (e.g., BOM is Mumbai; BPM is Hyderabad) and people typically have to look up what they mean anyway: somebody who knows what you need to do to fly from Sri Lanka to China via Thailand might still not recognize that KMG is in China.

Comment: @DavidRicherby You can always edit them in. I added the airline names, since most people are not familiar with codes that do not closely correspond to them, but I figured these airport destinations were common enough that they were either known or could easily be researched.

Comment: @DavidRicherby in the case of Bangkok, BKK was useful, as there are two international airports, BKK and DMK.

Comment: @dda I said don’t _just_ use airport codes, not don’t use them at all.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention your citizenship. If you require to pick up your luggage and check-in again, then you will have to pass through immigration. And in order to do that, you will need, depending on your citizenship, either:

1. A pre-arranged visa to enter Thailand.
2. A visa on arrival.
3. A visa exemption.

If you're from Sri Lanka, you'll need a pre-arranged (transit) visa. And another one on your way back, if you have the same itinerary in reverse. Getting off the plane, walking (probably a long walk) to and going through immigration and checking in again in 1.5 hours, best scenario, in Suvarnabhumi, is impossible. And today UL406 arrived 35 minutes late. You've just missed your plane. You'll be much better off with UL404...

Answer (score 0):

If there are checked bags, and there's no option to do through check-in, then the passenger will have to:

- have the necessary paperwork to enter Thailand (depends on citizenship, may require a visa)
- disembark (can take a while if at the back of a large aircraft)
- walk from gate to immigration
- go through immigration
- wait for bags
- go through customs
- go to departures
- get to the check-in counter
- check in / drop bags before the deadline (usually 1 hour before departure)
- go through passport control and security
- get to the boarding gate before the deadline

The main issue is getting to the check-in counter in time. If there's 1h30 between flights and the deadline is 1 hour, that means that **even with the inbound flight on time, the passenger needs to get from seat to check-in counter, via immigration, bag reclaim and customs in 30 minutes**. This seems impossible to me.

The Lucky Air website is only available in Chinese, and I couldn't find the actual deadline, but I doubt it's much less than one hour.

If you factor in the possibility that the flight might be delayed, that there could be a long queue at immigration, that bags may take a while to be delivered on the carousel, and that in the event the second flight is missed, it will be the passenger's responsibility to book and pay a new flight (possibly the return as well), you should factor at least 3 or 4 hours between arrival and departure.

The alternative would be to avoid checked-in luggage, as long as you can do online check-in (not sure that's actually possible on that flight) or can do the check-in at a transfer desk.